# How post messages to the yammer private group

Tags: windows-phone-8, yammer

I can able to get the messages from yammer private group using this link
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/3248147.json?access_token= + rawtoken)

but I used the same link for posting messages to the private group in yammer, for this I have wrote the below code. but it is behaving as get method only, I am unable to post the messages to the private group.

```
WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

                Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/3248147.json?access_token=" + rawtoken);
                student ns = new student();
                // wc.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer" + rawtoken;  //use discoEN token here
               // String data1 = "group-id=" + ns.group_id + "&body=" + ns.body;
                String data = "body=" + "hello";
                wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
                wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri,"post",data);

 private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Structure your post url like below, and keep the auth in the headers with the Bearer token format.

Notice that body is wrapped inside of query in the post format.

auth = "Bearer " + token

```
HTTParty.post("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?group_id=3248147",
              { 
                :headers => { "Authorization" => auth},
                :query => {"body" => 'hello' }
  })
```

Comment: Also, make sure that the app/token account is in the private group.